# Is it better to have more smaller records or fewer larger records in Lucene?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I'm in the process of indexing a huge set of log files for an application I work on using Lucene.net. Right now I am parsing my log files per entry (i.e. an entry can span multiple lines until the next log entry) and adding each log entry as a document in Lucene.

Each document contains the log entry (which is analyzed) and has some other fields (which are just stored), such as log line time, log line number and what kind of log it came from. I'm also giving each log entry document a guid to map a sequence of log entries back to the original source document and I can reorder them back by line number.

While I like the granularity of being able to search per line entry in my index (and I can rebuild the original document by hinging off the guid I've assigned each log file), I'm curious if this kind of index creation will be sustainable. As it is, I already have something like 25 million entries which represent logs from just a single year. My search speeds are still pretty fast, I can search these 25 million records in about a second or two.

Is it better to have fewer documents but each document is larger? Does it matter? Will I run into performance bottlenecks with Lucene when I have 50 million entries? 100 million? 500 million?  If I index only per log file I'd probably have 3 orders of magnitude less documents if I estimate that each log file has around 1000-20000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice with all these things is: performance will almost certainly not be your major problem. If the required functionality works best with a document per line, then do it that way.

That being said, Lucene's term dictionary looks something like:

```
term1 -> doc1 doc4 doc32 ...
term2 -> doc1 doc3 doc8
```

So having more documents will increase the size of the index.

Before you conclude that this is bad for performance, ask how you'll manage to return each line as its own search result if you do index the entire file as one document. You'll have to implement some secondary search on your search results, which is almost guaranteed to be slower than what Lucene does. So just let Lucene handle it.

As to your question about how high Lucene can scale: a patch was submitted a few years ago because the 32 bit IDs Lucene uses are too small. So there are people with indexes containing more than 2^32 = 4.2 billion documents.

Answer (score 2):

RavenDB uses Lucene internally for all it's querying and perf tests have shown that fewer indexes with more fields have better perf than more indexes with fewer fields.

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ravendb/a2oYOA_bHl8/discussion) for some actual numbers, for instance:

- 100 Indexes with a single property each    : 00:05:08
- 1 Index with 100 properties                : 00:02:01

This is for 25,600 docs (each having 100 string properties filled with guids).

**Note** these numbers are for RavenDB, but it uses Lucene extensively, so I'd be surprised if there was a big difference when using Lucene directly